# How fast can 10 integer multiplications be executed?

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing

This is self study, but not homework. I am reviewing some [slides](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s10/www/lectures/11-opt.pdf) I found online and have come across the following question.

---

### Question:

If the latency of integer multiply is $3$ and the cycles/issue is $1$ then

1. How fast can 10 *independent* int mults be executed?
   $$t_1 = a_1*b_1 \quad t_2 = a_2*b_2 \quad t_3 = a_3*b_3 \quad \cdots \quad t_{10} = a_{10}*b_{10}$$
2. How fast can $10$ *sequentially dependent* int mults be executed?
   $$t_1 = a_1*b_1 \quad t_2 = t_1*b_2 \quad t_3 = t_2*b_3 \quad \cdots\quad t_{10} = t_9*b_{10}$$

---

### Attempt:

Obviously the sequentially dependent case will take longer, because each multiply must wait for the previous multiply to finish. I'm not sure exactly how to interpret latency and cycles/issue in this context. My attempt.

1. Each multiply takes $3$ cycles, but we can start a new multiply each cycle (can we?), so we need $3 + 10 - 1 = 12$ cycles?
2. Naively, this would take $30$ cycles if we wait for the previous one to finish. It seems that we could do better though. For instance

   - $t_1$ first
   - $b_2*b_3$
   - wait a cycle
   - $t_2 = t_1* b_2$
   - $t_3 = t_1*(b_2*b_3)$

So the first $3$ mutliplys can be done in $7$ cycles instead of $9$. I think I just need to see a problem worked out and I'll be able to pick up whats going on.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80859/755

Comment: @D.W. Thank you, that is helpful. What is the relationship between throughput and cycles/issue?